# Why am I getting this error: "Labels must be a named vector!" in R?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am currently supplying a function with the argument "Labels" that are required. The function is within the Pigengene package and using the one.step.pigengene function. I am feeding in a vector of strings as the labels.

Here is the exact output and some additional details.

```
one.step.pigengene(subMelanoma, Labels = labels)
```

> Error in check.pigengene.input(Data = Data, Labels = Labels, na.rm = TRUE) : 
>   Labels must be a named vector!

```
class(labels)
#[1] "character"
labels[1:5]
#[1] NA                    "Recurred/Progressed" "Recurred/Progressed"
#[4] "Recurred/Progressed" "DiseaseFree"
```

Comment: Dont know about the Pigengene package but a named vector is vector like  Labels<-c("namea"="blabla","nameb"="toto"...)

Comment: the function is expecting `labels` to be a named vector. You can set names in different ways, such as `names(labels) <- c("label1", "label2", etc.)`

Comment: According to the reference https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/manuals/Pigengene/man/Pigengene.pdf , the labels argument have to be "A (preferably named) vector containing the Labels (condition types) for the
training Data. Names must agree with rows of Data". Check the example given in the reference to see how the labels were created for the aml & mds datasets.